# Bulk assign contribution page based on contribution type?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, import

Issue: We migrated about 5000 contacts from one CRM to CiviCRM.

The organization required historical data to be moved over, but also changed their membership pricing scheme which has been resolved with price sets + custom contribution page.

Members migrated over need to be assigned to this new contribution page so they can renew online.

All their contributions involving membership was tagged as "Member Dues". Unfortunately, we cannot seem to bulk assign this to the new contribution page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you! Never considered that Contribution Page was available as an import field. This should solve the issue nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried exporting those member dues contributions (including their contribution IDs as well as their Civi contact IDs), adding a column for contribution page ID, and importing that information back in as an update of the existing contributions?  If you've not tried that, it might be worth testing with a small subset of those member payments to see if you get the results you expect as far as updating the information.

Lesley